# How to handle throwing a lot of exceptions?

Tags: java, exception

So I've ran into a problem where I have to throw a lot of exceptions inside a function, and it takes up 90% of the code which makes it unclean and often hard to read.
What are ways to make it look / function better?

Context:
Making other functions to make it check for those cases is not doable in my case, because often times its oddly specific and it would take up 70% of the service.

Example:

```
public void problematicFunction(String string1, String string2, String string3, String string4) throws GenericException {

if(String1.someLogicHere) {
throw new GenericException("error_code", "something is wrong with" + string1)
}

if(String2.someLogicHere) {
throw new GenericException("error_code", "something is wrong with" + string2)
}

if(String2.someOtherLogicHere) {
throw new GenericException("error_code", "something else is wrong with" + string2)
}

if(String3.someLogicHere) {
throw new GenericException("error_code", "something is wrong with" + string3)
}

if(String4.someLogicHere) {
throw new GenericException("error_code", "something is wrong with" + string4)
}

mainlogic(string1,string2,string3,string4)
}
```

Edit1:
There is nothing in common in the logics, I used Strings as an example. Also it is important to throw them seperately because each error_code would point to a different issue (in the resp. payload)

Comment: More information about context and specifics including real code, might help

Comment: These checks don't have anything in common, so it's hard to refactor this. You could squeeze the condition into a Function/Supplier<Boolean> and then create one method that does the check and the throwing. But you still have to call that method multiple times.

Comment: Honestly the parts of this that are repeated look like they shouldn't be - if each is failing according to different logic, the error strings should probably be different as well. You could have something like a list of `Condition` objects storing a check function and a relevant string each. Without more context it's hard to improve this.

Comment: One other thing you might consider is if you really want to only fail on the first one. You might, but it can be useful to provide all the errors in one go, aggregating them into a single error. That would be faintly messy with exceptions but could be doable. Honestly I find exceptions in general to usually be messy, but in Java I guess they're the standard.

Answer (score 1):

If the logic doesn't have much in common, it's hard to do that, but you can do something like that in general(as someone mentioned in comments), or think of it better once you know all the logic for if statements.

```
    boolean checkExceptions(String string1, String string2, String string3, String string4) {
        if(String1.someLogicHere) return string1;
        if(String2.someLogicHere) return string2;
        if(String3.someLogicHere) return string3;
        if(String4.someLogicHere) return string4;
        return ""; // or create some NoException String
    }
    
    public void problematicFunction(String string1, String string2, String string3, String string4) throws GenericException {
        String checkExcp = checkExceptions(stirng1, string2, string3, string4);
        if(!checkExcp.isEmpty()){
            throw new GenericException("error_code", "something is wrong with" + checkExcp);
        }
        
        // main logic
    }
```